# How to check for error from rest API response in android?

Tags: android, spring

I am developing android app in which I send the login details to rest API and from that, I get the response, I want to check that is there any error in login details from server, as server send me a response

```
 {
    "timestamp": 1505309139410,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "exception": "org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/auth"
}
```

this is my json response

and this is my login user method

```
private void Loginuser(final String email_or_phone, final String user_password){

    Log.d(TAG,email_or_phone +" "+ user_password);
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";
    pDialog.setMessage("login ...");
    showDialog();

   JSONObject jobj= new JSONObject();

    try {
        jobj.put("username",email_or_phone);
        jobj.put("password",user_password);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, jobj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString() + "Login responce");
            hideDialog();
            try {
                boolean error = response.getBoolean("error");
               if(!error) {
                    String token = response.optString("token");
                   Log.d("Token string", token);
                        Intent home = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        home.putExtra("token",token);
                        startActivity(home);
                        finish();
               } //Error in login. Get the error message
               String errorMsg = response.getString("error");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    // Addinrg request to request queue
    Log.e("Responce string",jsonObjectRequest.toString());
    AppController.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest, tag_string_req);

}
```

I am getting error in `JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);` this line.

the error of json

`org.json.JSONException: No value for error
09-13 19:23:19.303 22852-22852/com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
09-13 19:23:19.303 22852-22852/com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getBoolean(JSONObject.java:410)
09-13 19:23:19.303 22852-22852/com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing W/System.err:     at com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing.activity.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:330)
09-13 19:23:19.303 22852-22852/com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing W/System.err:     at com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing.activity.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:324)
09-13 19:23:19.303 22852-22852/com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
09-13 19:23:19.303 22852-22852/com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
09-13 19:23:19.303 22852-22852/com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
09-13 19:23:19.303 22852-22852/com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-13 19:23:19.303 22852-22852/com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
09-13 19:23:19.303 22852-22852/com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
09-13 19:23:19.303 22852-22852/com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-13 19:23:19.303 22852-22852/com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
09-13 19:23:19.303 22852-22852/com.wowoni.bikesharing.bicyclesharing W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)`

this is my success response

```
{
"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI4NjU1MjUzMTE0IiwiYXVkIjoid2ViIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA1OTgzNTY2LCJpYXQiOjE1MDUzNzg3NjZ9.StHWCEHgR_OqwFy-3wYLbbjq0MWBGb1vmdQLlv8gb-DFSrAdAktnCzX6bq0UibUiXMIXjDiyhTFtn1VtHaqbuA"
```

}

Comment: what exactly is the error that you get

Comment: @NavneetKrishna i mention the json response in my question when i get but this is response when user credentials are incorrect  error {
"timestamp": 1505309139410,
"status": 401,
"error": "Unauthorized",
"exception": "org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"path": "/auth"
}

Answer (score 0):

You already receiving JSONObject as a parameter.

Your code should be like this:

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString() + "Login responce");
            hideDialog();
            try {
                String errorMsg = response.getString("error");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                int statusCode = response.getInt("status");
                String exception = response.getString("exception");
                String message = response.getString("message");
                String path = response.getString("path");

               // do whatever with this responses.

            }catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

I can't see "token" in your JSON. ensure that you will receive a token in your JSON.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: your parsing is wrong I parse and post the data for you.

Comment: See my updated answer. Do whatever with the response.

Comment: thanks for your code bt i am getting the same error actually i want to check if there is error or not and using that i am passing user to home screen i am checking with this condition  " if(errorMsg == null  && errorMsg ==" ") "

Comment: when user successfully login i am getting token bt in my case i am getting "json no value for error" error when i check if there is error in my response please anybody help me to get the desire result.

Comment: Post your success response in your question.

Comment: i added the response in my question